# What is the MATLAB equivalent of Excel's WORKDAY function?

Tags: excel, matlab, worksheet-function

Is there a simple way to do something equivalent to [`WORKDAY`](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Workday-Function.html) function of excel in matlab?

Thanks for your help

Laurent

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the function in the [matlab doc](http://es.mathworks.com/help/finance/wrkdydif.html)

```
Days = wrkdydif('9/1/2000', '9/11/2000', 1)

returns

Days =
       6
```

Will work in order to know which day is a work day You can use `isbuyday` [help doc](http://es.mathworks.com/help/finance/isbusday.html)

Example

```
Busday = isbusday('16 jun 2001')

Busday =

         0

Date = ['15 feb 2001'; '16 feb 2001'; '17 feb 2001'];
Busday = isbusday(Date)

Busday =

         1
         1
         0
```

Comment: FYI - this is dependent on having the finance toolbox.

Comment: This doesn't seem to match the linked description of Excel's `workday` function

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the date format option in [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html)

```
datestr(now,'ddd')
```

Outputs

```
Wed
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to match the linked description of Excel's `workday` function

Comment: @LuisMendo it is a lead as to how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the financial toolbox, you can use `wrkdydif`.  Otherwise, you'll have to write a function that iterates through the dates between the two input datas and compares them to a list of holidays you maintain.  You will also need to check the day of the week (using `weekday`) to ensure it is a M-F.